# Table to Link two entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have two entities - UserObj and Producer.

UserObj stores user-related profile data
Producer is a company that a userobj can be associated with.  To associate these two I wanted to make an entity that lets me access the data of each from one entity.

I'm trying to link the two - but I'm not quite sure how to do it and I bet it is something small.  Thanks for any and all help!

ProducerUser

```
    public class ProducerUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserObj")]
    public Guid UserObjID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Producer")]
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserObj UserObj { get; set; }
    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }

}
```

UserObj

```
    public class UserObj : Contact
{

    [Key]
    //public override string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid UserObjID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
   // [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
  //  [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }

    public static UserObj GetUserObj(string GUID, vfContext db)
    {
        Guid guidUser = new Guid(GUID);
        return db.UserObjs.Find(guidUser);
    }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }

}
```

Producer

```
    public class Producer : Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Wine> Wines { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish a many to many relationship add ICollection<> on both sides of the relationship. In your case:

To the class Producer add

```
public virtual ICollection<UserObj> UserObjs { get; set; }
```

To the class UserObj add

```
public virtual ICollection<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
```

After that you can remove the declaration of the class ProducerUser. EF will generate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the classes UserObj and Producer:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProducerUser> ProducerUsers { get; set; }
```